# How to save rss feed item as single page in PHP using SimpleXML

Tags: php, html, rss, simplexml

how to save rss feeds item as a subpage or any were in the domain using php. each item must be saved as a single page (html or php).

below given is the php code how i pulled the xml using simpleXML. i want to know a way to save this results as of each content (items) as a page (html or php).

```
    <?php

function getFeed($feed_url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);

    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        echo "
        <li>
          <a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a>
          <p href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->{'author'} . "</p>
          <a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->enclosure . "</a>

          ";

    echo "  </li>";
        }

    echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    $html = '<ul>';

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        $html .= "<li>
            <a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a>
            <p href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->{'author'} . "</p>
            <a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->enclosure . "</a>
            </li>";
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    // The name of the file
    $fileName = 'file.html';
    // Create the file
    $fileHandler = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
    // Send the $html variable to be written in the opened file
    fwrite($fileHandler, $html);
    // Close file
    fclose($fileHandler);
}
```

Comment: Sir, this helped me to make a page of the whole items loaded. but i want is as those li as a page. means save each item in a page. And sir the files is saved on main dir. how to make it on the sub dir like (pages/file name). your answer helped me half way there. thanks